# Memory issue with win2D in winrt app

Tags: c#, windows, winrt-xaml, win2d

I am using win2D for image effects, because of which memory keeps on increasing as we use the windows app and causes in crash.

ref: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Win2D

please let me know how handle memory leakage.

Comment: see : https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/issues/37

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing to a render target make sure you don't recreate it every frame. Just create your **CanvasRenderTarget** in the **CreateResources** event, and store it for reuse.